# Can't connect ssh via wireless interface but t works using eth0

Tags: ssh, linux-networking, router, wifi, ethernet

Suddenly I can't connect via `ssh` to a server using my wireless interface but I can do it using the eth0 interface with a cable connected directly to my router.

From my wireless interface I got:

```
$ ssh -vvv my_server
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 38: Applying options for my_server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XX.XXX.XX.XXX is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to XX.XXX.XX.XXX [XX.XXX.XX.XXX] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: connect to address XX.XXX.XX.XXX port 22: Network is unreachable
ssh: connect to host XX.XXX.XX.XXX port 22: Network is unreachable
```

and the `tcpdump` is:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -v -i any tcp port 22

tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
19:56:14.312414 wlp0s20f3 Out IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 25412, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    myhost.52266 > ec2-XX-XXX-XX-XXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x36d4 (incorrect -> 0xcc4d), seq 1642097124, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 1123249955 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
```

From my eth interface:

```
$ ssh -vvv my_server
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 38: Applying options for my_server
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname XX.XXX.XX.XXX is address
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/user/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to XX.XXX.XX.XXX [XX.XXX.XX.XXX] port 22.
debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10
debug1: Connection established.
```

and the `tcpdump` is:

```
$ sudo tcpdump -v -i any tcp port 22

tcpdump: data link type LINUX_SLL2
tcpdump: listening on any, link-type LINUX_SLL2 (Linux cooked v2), snapshot length 262144 bytes
22:14:16.335219 enp0s31f6 Out IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 48434, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    ws5.51632 > ec2-XX.XXX.XX.XXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.ssh: Flags [S], cksum 0x36d1 (incorrect -> 0xdbb4), seq 1199071061, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 151306527 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:14:16.390032 enp0s31f6 In  IP (tos 0x0, ttl 48, id 0, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 60)
    ec2-XX.XXX.XX.XXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.ssh > ws5.51632: Flags [S.], cksum 0xdc56 (correct), seq 1641064052, ack 1199071062, win 62643, options [mss 1440,sackOK,TS val 2605867526 ecr 151306527,nop,wscale 7], length 0
22:14:16.390126 enp0s31f6 Out IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 48435, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    ws5.51632 > ec2-XX.XXX.XX.XXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.ssh: Flags [.], cksum 0x36c9 (incorrect -> 0xfd95), ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 151306582 ecr 2605867526], length 0
22:14:16.397623 enp0s31f6 Out IP (tos 0x10, ttl 64, id 48436, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 84)
    ws5.51632 > ec2-XX.XXX.XX.XXX.eu-central-1.compute.amazonaws.com.ssh: Flags [P.], cksum 0x36e9 (incorrect -> 0x92b6), seq 1:33, ack 1, win 502, options [nop,nop,TS val 151306590 ecr 2605867526], length 32: SSH: SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3
```

My working interface is enp0s31f6 (former eth0):

```
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
```

and the failed one is the wifi market with `noqueue`:

```
3: wlp0s20f3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
```

I find very interesting that the addresses are given as IPv4 addresses in my `~/.ssh/config`, but the log says TCP(6). I guess that means IPv6. I have tried to force it with the option `-4` but the result is the same.

my `~/.ssh/config` is:

```
Host $ ssh -vvv my_server
   Hostname XX.XXX.XX.XXX
   User ubuntu
   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/my_id.pem
```

with `ethtool -S wlp0s20f3` I can see that there are no dropped packets in the connection.

Which may be the cause ?

Comment: TCP(6) in decode of an IP header (an IPv4 header!) does not mean IPv6, it means TCP over IPv4, see https://www.iana.org/assignments/protocol-numbers/protocol-numbers.xhtml . On your tcpdump try `-n` (maybe `-nn`) to see actual addresses not a mapping that _might_ be ambiguous, and `or icmp` to see the exact error coming back (e.g. is its claimed origin address the router or not)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I had the same `debug3: set_sock_tos: set socket 3 IP_TOS 0x10` trace that you mention and turns out that, for my specific case, I solved it with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1418608), which was related to how my router managed the QoS of the WiFi. Simply by adding the `-o IPQoS=none` I was finally able to connect:

```
axel@PTT426:~$ ssh -o IPQoS=none -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519 -vvv git@github.com
OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: include /etc/ssh/ssh_config.d/*.conf matched no files
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 21: Applying options for *
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts' -> '/home/axel/.ssh/known_hosts'
debug3: expanded UserKnownHostsFile '~/.ssh/known_hosts2' -> '/home/axel/.ssh/known_hosts2'
debug2: resolving "github.com" port 22
debug3: resolve_host: lookup github.com:22
debug3: ssh_connect_direct: entering
debug1: Connecting to github.com [140.82.121.3] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
```

By adding this into the top of my `~/.ssh/config` file I got if fixed for every `git` and `ssh` operations:

```
Host *
  IPQoS=none
```

Hope it helps! :)

Comment: Somehow the problem vanished for me after one week approximately. Given that you were able to reproduce it, I will take this answer as the accepted one.

Comment: For me the problem appeared after upgrading to Windows 11 (Windows firewall/VPN/group policies can be at play) - solution above fixed ssh/git pull, but telnet HOSTNAME 22 still does not work for some reason